# add event handler to last item of li within a map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I attach a click event in my last item of a map? I didn't see the console been trigger. No error in my below code

```
{props.items.map((obj,index) => {

    if(props.items.length === index - 1){
        console.log('is last iteration')
    }

    return(
        <li key={obj.key}>{obj.name}</li>
        )
})}
```

Comment: Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/smoleniuszek/3mv48L6j/12/) fiddle,i couldnt make stackoverflow use jsx so i made this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to:

```
{props.items.map((obj,index) => {    
    return props.items.length-1 === index?
           <li key={obj.key} ()=>{
              //your code
           }>{obj.name}</li>
           :
           <li key={obj.key}>{obj.name}</li>;         
})}
```